# Running Mac OS X 10.6 but "uname -m" shows i386

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, 64-bit

I just got a Mac and I have Snow Leopard installed. I checked my arch type and it says i386.

How is it possible? 10.6 is 64-bit, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Mac OS X still starts up using a 32-bit kernel. If your computer supports the 64-bit kernel, and you start up using the 64-bit kernel it will display x86_64 instead of i386.

You can find out more about the use of the 32-bit kernel by default in the [Why does my Mac OS X 10.6 kernel run in 32-bit mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/23214/why-does-my-mac-os-x-10-6-kernel-run-in-32-bit-mode) question here on Super User.

Comment: can i make 64bit default?

Comment: Read the accepted answer in the Superuser post that Chealion linked to. Short answer is *yes but you don't need to to run 64-bit applications*.